# How to add a class to a button in yii2-export

Tags: yii2

I'm using [Yii2-export plugin](https://demos.krajee.com/export). By default, the button has a class `btn btn-secondary btn-default` and I want to add my classes to the button. I do it as follows:

```php
<?= ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'dropdownOptions' => [
        'label' => 'Export',
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm font-weight-bold',
        'icon' => '<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt icon-nm"></i>'
    ],
    'columnSelectorOptions' => [
        'icon' => '<i class="fas fa-list icon-nm"></i>',
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm font-weight-bold',
    ],
    'exportConfig' => ...
    'columns' => ...
]); ?>
```

But as a result, this is rendered:

```html
<button id="w4-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm font-weight-bold btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" title="Export data in selected format" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt icon-nm"></i> Эскпортировать</button>
```

That is, my classes are just written at the beginning and not applied. What should I do?

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: @InsaneSkull 4.x